# semantics of svelte syntax greater then in `action={trigger}> {$open ? 'Close' : 'Open'}`

Tags: syntax, svelte

I came across this syntax  from example in  ([MeltUI -- a svelte based component library](https://melt-ui.com/docs/usage)

```
<Button on:click={() => console.log('clicked')} {...$trigger} action={trigger}>
  {$open ? 'Close' : 'Open'}
</Button>
```

I want to understand what does the `>` in `action={trigger}> {$open ? 'Close' : 'Open'}` used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the end of the opening `Button` tag: `<Button ... >`

| Attribute | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `on:click={() => console.log('clicked')}` | `click` event handler |
| `{...$trigger}` | spreading of multiple properties from store `trigger` |
| `action={trigger}` | `action` property being set to JS value `trigger` |

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now. Partially, I want to blame javascript exotic syntax :).